# Issue accessing Node-Red from IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I started using Node-Red from IBM Bluemix. I successfully created the Node-Red Starter plan and started working with Node-Red. After about a week of using my browser started responding with

This site can’t provide a secure connection mybluemixapp.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I can access the URL from my companies network and the connection is secure. I have done a bit of googling and tried the solution post [here](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/fix-err-ssl-protocol-error/) 
but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you seeing this error in Chrome?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes

Comment: Provide more details in your question about recent changes. Chrome caches certificates. Flush the Chrome cache and reboot your system. If you just implemented/changed SSL certificates, this will usually solve the problem. You can also use a site like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to test your SSL setup.

Comment: I have run the Bluemix URL through the ssltest and id fine. I have also run the browser test and it is fine. I have disable my network connection and tethered the computer to my mobile and Bluemix is fine. It appears to point to my service provider.

Comment: Do you have IPv6 AAAA records in your DNS server?

Comment: Apologies for late response. I have added a DNS and alternate DNS addresses on the network interface (IPv4) the DNS addresses where provided by my ISP. That solved my problem. Thanks for your help.